# How alexa measure websites like Instagram,Telegram,... trrafic?

Tags: instagram, web-traffic, alexa-skills-kit

I  know that Alexa use its toolbars in web browsers to estimate and measure websites traffic, some websites like Instagram and Telegram that their user use Apps for connect to content of them and there is no toolbar in that apps but they rank is very high(Instagram = 24)!!; 
how Alexa does measure their traffic?